# Select random rows up to a limit

Tags: mysql, select

```
SELECT *
FROM my_players
WHERE player_type = 'IF'
ORDER BY cardweight / rand() DESC limit 3
```

That is my current query, What I am trying to do is select random rows for which I have the * in my query, so I am trying to get the psbin (which is a column in my table) it is a int and I want the psbin of all these rows combined not to go over 250k.

Create table statement is:

```
CREATE TABLE `my_players` ( 
`myplayer_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
`player_id` int(11) NOT NULL, 
`First_Name` varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
`Last_Name` varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
`Rare` varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
`Foot` varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
`Height` varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
`Date_Of_Birth` varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
`player_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
`player_nation` int(11) NOT NULL, 
`player_club` int(11) NOT NULL, 
`player_league` int(11) NOT NULL, 
`player_type` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'GOLD', 
`player_pos` varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
`totwImage` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, 
`psbin` int(11) NOT NULL, 
`xboxbin` int(11) NOT NULL, 
`ps3bin` int(11) NOT NULL, 
`360bin` int(11) NOT NULL, 
`xmin` int(11) NOT NULL, 
`xmax` int(11) NOT NULL, 
`pmin` int(11) NOT NULL, 
`pmax` int(11) NOT NULL, 
`cardweight` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1', 
`definitionId` int(21) NOT NULL, 
`resourceId` int(21) NOT NULL, 
`player_added` datetime NOT NULL, 
`player_status` enum('0','1') NOT NULL, 
`player_rating` int(11) NOT NULL, 
`Attribute1` int(11) NOT NULL, 
`Attribute2` int(11) NOT NULL, 
`Attribute3` int(11) NOT NULL, 
`Attribute4` int(11) NOT NULL, 
`Attribute5` int(11) NOT NULL, 
`Attribute6` int(11) NOT NULL, 
`available` int(11) NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (`myplayer_id`) 
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3207 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Answer (score 4):

If I understand you correctly you want to add up psbin values up to 250.000 from random rows

```
SELECT *
FROM my_players, (SELECT @psbin := 0) x
WHERE player_type = 'IF' 
AND (@psbin := @psbin + psbin) <= 250000
ORDER BY RAND();
```

Comment: it returns empty result

Comment: here you can take a look @Mihai http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/633b75/1

Comment: @JackSmith Every psbin in your sample data is larger than 250.000 so you are asking for conidtions which are not in your data,the query works http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bd690/2

Comment: ok so when i have psbin combined from all 3 rows it should not go pass 250k so you are saying i can not do that because all of them will pass 250k right?

Comment: @JackSmith Here is the query running with 3 values under 250k http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d3e8e/1 What is not clear?

Comment: it is not working in phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

It is not easy to *efficiently* get N random rows from a table.  [*My blog*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/random) provides 3 efficient ways to do such, depending on details about your needs.

- You have `AUTO_INCREMENT`, but are there any gaps?
- Can you add another column to facilitate the random fetch?